# How to get stack trace information for logging in production when using the GAC

Tags: .net-3.5, gac, stack-trace, pdb-files, nlog

I would like to get stack trace (file name and line number) information for logging exceptions etc. in a production environment. The DLLs are installed in the GAC. Is there any way to do this?

[This article](http://www.elumenotion.com/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=23) says about putting PDB files in the GAC:

> You can spot these easily because they will say you need to copy the debug symbols (.pdb file) to the GAC. In and of itself, that will not work.

I know this article refers to debugging with VS but I thought it might apply to logging the stacktrace also.

I've followed the instructions for the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628565/) except for unchecking Optimize code which they said was optional.

I copied the dlls and pdbs into the GAC but I'm still not getting the stack trace information. Here's what I get in the log file for the stack trace:

```
OnAuthenticate at offset 161 in file:line:column <filename unknown>:0:0
ValidateUser at offset 427 in file:line:column <filename unknown>:0:0
LogException at offset 218 in file:line:column <filename unknown>:0:0
```

I'm using NLog.

My NLog layout is:

```
layout="${date:format=s}|${level}|${callsite}|${identity}|${message}|${stacktrace:format=Raw}"
```

${stacktrace:format=Raw} being the relevant part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try raw in lowercase:

```
   ${stacktrace:format=raw}
```

If that doesn't work try:

```
   ${exception:format=stacktrace}
```

Comment: Neither worked though the second one gave me a nicer layout of the method names: CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller => MembershipLogin.Page_Load => MembershipLogin.Configure

Comment: Did you ever find out how to get line numbers?

Comment: perhaps you should ask a coherent question?

Comment: plz answer if u know..main goal is to know how to get line numbers

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
new Throwable().printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
String stackTrace = sw.toString();
```

The string stackTrace will have the stackstrace of the current thread

Comment: Thanks, though I don't really want to change the NLog source.