# Compile ASP.NET MVC 2 application in Release mode, but have detailed error messages

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, compilation

Good day!

I'd like to compile my MVC application in Release mode, but have line numbers in error messages which I write to log.

Can this be achived by setting "Build" -> "Advanced" -> "Debug Info" -> "Full"

Default for Debug is "full", for Release "pdb-only".

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can.

See also [Getting line number from pdb in release mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935726/getting-line-number-from-pdb-in-release-mode) and [Display lines number in Stack Trace for .NET assembly in Release mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628565/display-lines-number-in-stack-trace-for-net-assembly-in-release-mode)