# Generate PDB files when compilation debug="false" for ASP.NET files?

Tags: asp.net, release, pdb-files

I want to set compilation debug="false" to get release mode dll's compiled on the fly from aspx files.

However, I still want line numbers and such on errors as you find when you compile a DLL project with pdbonly set.

If you're looking to do that, you can find a great answer on this question: [Display lines number in Stack Trace for .NET assembly in Release mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628565/display-lines-number-in-stack-trace-for-net-assembly-in-release-mode)

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this a WSP (Web Site Project) or a WAP (Web Application Project) setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you can do that on web.config, on the compilers

I have place here the Trace command, you can set any compiler options

```
<system.codedom>
 <compilers>
 <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" compilerOptions="/define:TRACE" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider,System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" warningLevel="4">
 <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
 <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
</compiler>
<Compilers>
```

Compiler options that you can use
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ds95cz0(VS.71).aspx

Comment: Just FYI, I added to compilerOptions="/debug:pdbonly"