# Remote Debugging Class Library for ClickOnce App

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, clickonce, remote-debugging

I am trying to set up remote debugging on one of our internal systems as there is a function in a class library that keeps failing for our users but not me. I have the folder share to my remote debugger folder set up and I can attach to the process on their machine but I get the following message:

- `The following module was built either with optimizations enabled or without debug information: ....`

How do I satisfy this requirement?

I checked and optimizations is not enabled but how do I get the .pdb files to the user when using `ClickOnce`?  Is that even my issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the project you're publishing via ClickOnce:

- Open Properties for the project
- Click the Publish (vertical) tab
- Click the Application Files button

From this screen, you can add/remove files (like .pdb files) from the ClickOnce deployment.

You do **not** need to use a Debug release to include .pdb files - Release mode can be used.

More info about .NET .pdb files [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457095/release-generating-pdb-files-why), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628565/display-lines-number-in-stack-trace-for-net-assembly-in-release-mode), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791696/how-to-get-line-numbers-in-the-stacktrace-of-an-exception-thrown-in-net-to-sh).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you could publish the pdb's with the app.