# Unable to publish .PDB file for a Website application during TFS (2018.3) build process

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfsbuild

We are facing an issue related to .PDB files for Website application and here is the details:

1. If we publish the website from Visual Studio 2017 (right click on website and Publish) I can able to see .PDB files.
2. We tried with command line query also but its not able to publsih the .PDB files.
3. Also we are not able to publish the .PDB files as part of the TFS 2018.3 build (vNext build).

FYI, I have followed all the suggestions mentioned in other post ([Visual Studio 2012 Website Publish Not Copying .pdb files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19053738/visual-studio-2012-website-publish-not-copying-pdb-files)) but it doesnt worked for me.

The reason for asking different questions is, the other post was related to Visual Studio and this is related to TFS 2018.3.

Thanks,

Sam

Comment: Can you share which command line you tried and what is yout build definition?

Comment: msbuild C:\*****\website.publishproj /p:Configuration=Release /p:DeployOnBuild=true "/p:PublishProfile=C:\***\PublishProfiles\****.pubxml" /p:DebugSymbols=true /p:DebugType=full

Answer (score 0):

I can able to resolve the issue by adding below MS arguments in vNext Build,

/p:DebugType=pdbonly 
/p:OutputPath="$(Build.SourcesDirectory)****\Bin"

Thank you