# Exception.StackTrace line number shows only in debugger and is missing when reading its value

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, stack-trace

I am debugging an WCF project (with debug constant on) and come to this problem. I want to log the line number from the StackTrace of an ecxeption when caught

```
try
{
    // ...
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     string message = "Error: " + ex.StackTrace;
     // ...
}
```

And all I got in the `message` variable only contains the call stack and method names. What's weird is if I expand the `ex` variable in the debugger, I can see the full stack trace with line number. Only if I use the property directly will I get the truncated message.

See the screenshot. In the watch window I added 2 variables: `ex` while expanded, and ex.StackTrace. You can see even in the watch window, when accessing directly the line number is stripped.

So what is causing this behavior?

[image]

Comment: I trimmed some empty space from the screenshot to make it easier to see.  It was pretty wide.

Comment: Does this help you?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791696/how-to-get-line-numbers-in-the-stacktrace-of-an-exception-thrown-in-net-to-sh

Comment: @Amy Thanks for tidying up for me. You reminded me to check the Debugging information setting and it's on `Full`. When I try again, the line numbers appear normally everywhere - the problem disappeared! Now I can't duplicate it even on a Release build when Debugging info is set to None and a Clean & Rebuild- the line numbers are still there. There must be some messed up settings...