# VB Projects always building in Debug Mode

Tags: vb.net, debugging, compiler-construction, release, pdb-files

I ran into an issue today where VB is behaving differently from C#.  The issue is as follows.

Also note this is for .Net 4.0.

- Both projects are set to build in release mode
- Both projects are in the same solution
- The solution is set to build in release
- Both projects output to a Release folder in bin / obj

Everything seems to be okay except for one thing.  When inspecting the files with a tool such as http://assemblyinformation.codeplex.com/ the VB projects show as Debug and the C# projects show as Release.

I tracked this down to a setting in the Advanced Compiler Options for the pdb files.  If the debug info output for VB is set to anything other than none - then the project builds in debug mode (keep in mind it still outputs to the release folder).  C# does not exhibit this behavior.

I did a blog post here to work around the issue - but would love to know the root cause if any one knows.

http://tsells.wordpress.com/2012/03/08/vb-projects-always-building-in-debug-mode/

Comment: I suspect your tool is reporting incorrect information. Do note that [whether or not debug info is emitted has absolutely nothing to do with whether the assembly is compiled in "Debug" or "Release" mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457095/release-generating-pdb-files-why/5457250#5457250).

Comment: There were many discussions surrounding this in other areas.  So how would you determine if it was debug or release mode just by examining the dll / executable?

Comment: Its also worth noting that the tool shows the project as being optimized - but debug mode.

Comment: What does that *mean*? Optimized but debug mode?

Comment: I did some research and this tool is using the DebuggableAttribute class and is referencing the IsJITTrackingEnabled.  If it is enabled - it shows the assembly as debug mode.  It is looking at the JITOptimized attribute on the debug class to tell if optimization is enabled.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggableattribute.isjittrackingenabled(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I don't think the tool is wrong.  Note that with the same settings - C# projects still show in release mode.  This is isolated to VB only.