# Distribute my VB.Net App

Tags: vb.net

I've made a simple calculator. My VB.Net (WinForm) App is inside Bin\Debug.
I have some files. These are the files:

- AppName.exe
- AppName.pdb
- AppName.vshost.exe
- AppName.vshost.exe.manifest
- AppName.xml

What I want to do is to run my app on another computer. I've installed the right
Framework, in this case is 4.0

Could anybody help me telling me if I've got to copy all files (to the other computer) to run my app, or just the AppName.exe is enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build your application in `Release` mode and then copy the contents of `bin\Release` to the other computer. Create a shortcut on the new computer to `AppName.exe` and rename it to an appropriate name if you wish.

Note: Building in `Release` mode does not include the `.pdb` files, which are necessary for proper debugging and it also optimizes the compiled code.

Comment: By default it is indeed disabled, though including the pdb files (you can set it in the Release build properties as "pdb-only") can greatly improve the logging of errors (and locating problems in your code). Also read [this great answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5457250/578843).