# Remove .pdb file on Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

When I compile a .sln file with Visual Studio 2013 a .pdb file is generated. How can I disable the creation of the .pdb file?

Comment: The `.pdb` file should not be generated when compiling the `.sln` file in `Release` configuration. Does that help?

Comment: @AnthonyForloney Still happening after cleaning and rebuilding, will double check tomorrow, thanks.

Comment: @AnthonyForloney I'm using the Release directory, the executable from there still contains the path of a pdb file from the project. Active solution configuration is Release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Project Properties see "Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Debugging -> Generate Debug Info".

Also see:

[PDB Files - What are they and how to generate them](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yash/archive/2007/10/12/pdb-files-what-are-they-and-how-to-generate-them.aspx)

[.net - Release generating .pdb files, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457095/release-generating-pdb-files-why)

Those are relevant to Visual Studio 2013 also. Be sure to read the stackoverflow thread since it has important information.

Comment: Sorry, this is for a lower version.

Comment: I do not understand "lower version". If you mean that the articles describe previous versions, note that they apply to the current version also.

Comment: I'm sorry, you were right. It actually appears on your first link, didn't notice.

Comment: This explains how to disable just the pdb file and that is what you asked so why the downvote?

Comment: My vote is locked, add any text to it and I'll upvote back. Sorry!

Comment: Mistakes happen. I have edited my answer so perhaps you can upvote now but the important thing is that I know I did help you.

Comment: @user34600 Done and I'm really sorry! I appreciate you, thanks :)

Comment: VS 2015: Project Properties -> Build -> Advanced -> Debug Info: none

Comment: @r3mark: This only works for C#. How can I do it for C/C++ ?

Answer (score 5):

I found it.

Project -> Properties -> Build

Last category there is Output, click the Advanced button and the Debug info should be none.

Comment: You asked how to disable the pdb file, correct? This will disable all debug output, and that is not what you asked.

Comment: @user34660 Actually, it is. There's a drop-down there with 3 options: none, create pdb and full debug information. If you use none, it doesn't create.