# Visual Studio 2022 place referenced dll into subdirectory of bin folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I have created a c#-project in Visual Studio 2022 which is using the nuget-package "Microsoft.Data.SqlClient".
This package brings along about 60(!) dll, so that my \bin\release folder is now really full.

To get more clarity in this folder, I was wondering if these dll could be placed in a subdirectory of \bin\release, for example \bin\release\dll.

I'm also wondering why there are *.xml and *.pdb files genereated for every *.dll file in \bin\release.
Could this be suppressed?

Thanks for any suggestions!
Tobias

Comment: Short answer is no, long answer is yes, but AFAIK that would involve lots of effort. Including a [custom build target](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build) that moves these DLLs into a subdirectory and [hooking into the assembly resolver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/resolve-loads#the-correct-way-to-handle-assemblyresolve) in order to load those DLLs.

Comment: PDB file generation can be disabled in the project properties Build > General > Debug symbols. XML file generation can be disabled also there at Build > Output > Documentation file.

Comment: Why do you care about the number of DLL-s? Your code is using those features so the DLL-s need to be there. Typical users won't look into your release folder but will use a shortcut to start your program.

Comment: What is your project template? Is it .net 6, .net 7 or .net framework?

Comment: the pdb file generation seems to work only for the main program, but not für nuget packages. They are still generated

Comment: This is not a "normal" programm for typical users mit shortcuts. It will be some kind of portable app, so you do have to look in the release folder to start the exe.

Comment: I am using .net framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, you are using .net framework, you can refer to the following steps to achieve your requirement:

First, you can add post build event in property of the project to move the DLLs into lib folder:
[image]

You can refer to this command line in post build event:

```
ROBOCOPY "$(TargetDir) " "$(TargetDir)lib\ " /XF *.exe *.config *.manifest  /XD lib logs data /E /IS /MOVE if %errorlevel% leq 4 exit 0 else exit %errorlevel%
```

Then add this code in your App.config file:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <probing privatePath="lib" />
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

It looks like this:
[image]

Finally build the project it will be clean in the folder and the .exe file works fine.
[image]

Comment: Great solution, works perfekt!

Comment: @TobiasGregorczyk I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark my reply as the accepted answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

You hardly will be able to run your executable without the dependencies. Regarding the .pdb debug info files, a great answer is provided here: [Release generating .pdb files, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5457250/8327106)
Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, now I understand a little bit better what its about the pdb files

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the Probing element

Something like this

```
<configuration>  
   <runtime>  
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">  
         <probing privatePath="bin;bin2\subbin;bin3"/>  
      </assemblyBinding>  
   </runtime>  
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I do know how this can help me?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).