# MSVS 2010. Solution projects refuse to be debugged

Tags: visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions

I have created several new solution configurations based on *debug* one and then killed standard *debug* and *release*.

I wonder why all of solution project refuse to be debugged. When I put break point into the very first line of code (no matter if it is windows-forms application, console, test project...) MSVS tells me, that "breakpoint will not be currently hit".

I cleaned the solution and rebuild after that but in vain.

What should I check to make my projects debuggable?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alike question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628565/display-lines-number-in-stack-trace-for-net-assembly-in-release-mode).

I should have set [project properties/build/advanced/output/debug info] to something except [none] option.