# Throw exception in the line where the method is called

Tags: c#, .net, exception, frameworks

When i use the Math library. like this.

```
 14-   int Result = 0;
 15-   Math.DivRem(1, 0, out Result);
```

The exception is marked in the line 15, but if i use my own Math Library, like this.

```
class MyMath
{
    public static decimal DivRem(int a, int b)
    {
        return a / b;
    }
}
```

and then call it.

```
 14-   int Result = 0;
 15-   MyMath.DivRem(1, 0);
```

The error is market inside my static DivRem in the line "return a / b;"

How can i achieve that?

ideas? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Put your own math library in a separate assembly where the calling assembly only references the compiled release version.

Comment: I have my library in the same solution as my WebSite,how can i add the reference to the release dll version?

Comment: Remove it from the solution (put it in its own) and then Add Reference and browse for the .dll.

Comment: I have now, my release Dll added to my project, and the exception still in the same place.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628565/display-lines-number-in-stack-trace-for-net-assembly-in-release-mode) question. The PDB seems to hold the debug information you would need to get those line numbers. Since I doubt there are PDB files for all the classes in the .NET framework, I think you are out of luck. I may be wrong, and they may be available, but at least you know what to look for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can instruct the debugger to step through (rather than into) the method with an attribute; I suspect this will also cause it to show the Exception at the call site, but I'm not certain.

```
class MyMath
{
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public static decimal DivRem(int a, int b)
    {
        return a / b;
    }
}
```

Comment: This attribute is only for the debugger, so it behave like a framework method, but the exception is still inside.