# Line numbers on stack trace

Tags: c#, winforms, stack-trace

When I get an unhandled exception fault I capture the exception and save to a log, also I give an option to email using the standard email client on which ever PC I am on.  My program is running in "Released" mode but the exception's stack trace does not have any line numbers to the source code.  What might I be doing wrong?  Is there an option to include these?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display lines number in Stack Trace for .NET assembly in Release mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/628565/display-lines-number-in-stack-trace-for-net-assembly-in-release-mode)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need to include the PDB files, I believe these contain extra information such as the line numbers.

Comment: Just an addition - For the files deployed in GAC you will have to deploy the PDB's to - %systemroot%\symbols\dll

Answer (score 2):

You have to include debugging information in the build and then deploy the file.  Include the PDB file with the executable code.