# Which method in the stack trace does the exception belong to?

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, exception, stack-trace

In a stack trace - has the exception occurred in the last method, in the method before the last method or in the method that was to follow (i.e. it didn't get that far because of the exception)?

So, in the following example, is Method3 the method in which the exception occurred? Or is it a 'Method4' (it only got as far as completing method 3)?

```
STACK TRACE:
Method3()
Method2()
Method1()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The exception was thrown in Method3, and the rest of the stack trace shows the calling chain to Method3. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628565/display-lines-number-in-stack-trace-for-net-assembly-in-release-mode) shows you how to get line numbers in the stack trace too (even for release builds), which will clarify exactly where the exception is being thrown.

Comment: Didn't realise I could get such specific details from an exception in release. This will come in VERY handy.