# Exception Tracing on Web Services - .net

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, web-services, wcf

I have a  Web service call, which is already tested in Local Environment , Works Great no exceptions, I have tested it in one of our servers and it works great there as well. But here comes the main server were i need to set up the Web service , I did deploy my code, got the Web Service up and Running .. Now a part of my calls 50% work great( where only few fields are sent out in a call) , they get me responses and the other part (where there are many fields )just return an exception.."Object Reference Not Set to an Instance of Object".

I have avoided all the possibilities for an null reference exception to occur, But still i get that, and I am kind of lost as i don't know what exact point the Code is failing, I have enabled tracing, it doesn't help.. I tried getting the exception information by turning on the NullReferenceException in CLR

```
[FaultException: Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) +14799942
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) +622
   WebServiceX.OrderingSoap.ProcessTeleReseller(ProcessTeleResellerRequest request) +0
   WebServiceX.OrderingSoapClient.ProcessTeleReseller(OrderHeader Ord_Header, Int32 Num_PotsLines) +105
   WFTransmitOrder2.SaveOrder() +997
   WFTransmitOrder2.IBTransmit_Click(Object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e) +24
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.OnClick(ImageClickEventArgs e) +134
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +204
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3804
```

this doesn't help much either, as i want to know the line number inside my Web Service class.

Why does this kind of issues happen, what is the relationship between Web Services and servers ?  These Web Services are hosted on IIS on one of our communications servers for different company's . It is working on the servers we have hosted but not on the Customer Servers

Any Help is highly appreciated..I have been stuck on this issue for a while now :)

Thanks

Comment: If you really want the line numbers to be included in your stack trace, you need to add debug information from .pdb files.  But be very careful - this is essentially equivalent to giving away your source code!  Not advised for sensitive items.  Info on how to generate PDBs for Released code:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/628565/display-lines-number-in-stack-trace-for-net-assembly-in-release-mode

Comment: You can debug your web service in the IIS too. To do this you have to a installed Visual Studio on the same server. Then you can use “Attach to Process”. Maybe the request it is a different than you expected, for that you can use the svc log. Configurable in the web.config - <system.diagnostics>

Comment: Thanks for your reply's guys, I have the PDB file but still it doesnt give me any line number... and this Server is not owned by our company so we dont have permissions to Install Visual studio There :(