# C# Exception is not returning the filename and LineNumber

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, exception

I have an application that writes/logs the `Exception` in the database. All codes works okay when I am using the Visual Studio to run the project. But when I compiled or when I created the installer and installed to my PC. The `FileName` and `LineNumber` is null.

I am using the code below:

```
 var sTrace = new StackTrace(sqlEx, true);
 if (sTrace != null)
  {
    // var frame = sTrace.GetFrame(sTrace.FrameCount - 1);
    var frame = sTrace.GetFrames().Last();
    LineNumber = frame.GetFileLineNumber();
    SrcFileName = frame.GetFileName();
    MethodName = frame.GetMethod().ReflectedType.FullName + "." + frame.GetMethod().Name;
  }
```

Comment: Is .pdb included in your installer?

Comment: I don't think so cause when I open the folder in Program Files, I can't see any .pdb file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debug builds tend to include *.pdb files, which include line number/file info. Typically, for a "production" or "installer" build you do not tend to output these files.

There is nothing stopping you include the pdb's with your installer if you want this information.

Comment: thanks, i tried configuring the project and it still not generating the .pdb file. I followed the answer in this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628565/display-lines-number-in-stack-trace-for-net-assembly-in-release-mode

Comment: I already resolved it. I added the Debug Symbol in application Folder when creating the installer. Thanks.