# c# stack trace line number not showing despite having provided pdb file

Tags: c#, debugging, stack-trace, line-numbers

[image]

As you can see the line numbers are replaced by a guid. This only happpens sometimes and depends on which part of the solution I'm in. The method is relatively big and right now I'm using console logs to track those kind of errors, which is inconvenient.

I actually did follow the instructions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628565/display-lines-number-in-stack-trace-for-net-assembly-in-release-mode) post.

What could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, it looks like Unity is causing this issue. Right after posting it, it kind of resolved itself (UnityEditor crashed (beta version, hopefully not my fault^^) and on restart the line numbers finally appeared^^)