# VS2010: Why It's not possible to watch variables in debug mode?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, watch

I'm developing a win project with VS2010 (VB.NET). But sometimes I get messsages while trying to watch a variable in debug mode:

" 'EntityMaster' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level. "

EntityMaster is a variable.

Comment: Is EntityMaster, in a function? More details around it's scope please.

Comment: @Carnotaurus: It's been declared in a function which I'm debugging it step by step but still get the message above

Comment: Are you sure it is accessible at the level of the function rather than being defined in a code block? If not then I would go down bitxwise's path.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's possible that your variable is being optimized out by Visual Studio. See here for more info:

[What does "Optimize Code" option really do in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113866/what-does-optimize-code-option-really-do-in-visual-studio)