# What is the `optimize` parameter in the build definition of a vproj file?

Tags: vb.net, dll, msbuild

I have a **vproj** file that I  have opened in notepad,

What is the job of the `optimize` parameter here, what would be the difference between `True` and `False`?

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">

<DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>

<DefineDebug>false</DefineDebug>

<DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>

<Optimize>true</Optimize> <!-- Here -->
```

Comment: Thanks @Sam, do you know if this option would have any bearing on the dll which is built ?? in terms of size ?

Comment: Actually, it would be better to just mark this question as a duplicate, rather than for you or me to write up an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without optimizations the compiler produces very dumb code - each command is compiled in a very straightforward manner, so that it does the intended thing. The Debug builds have optimizations disabled by default, because without the optimizations the produced executable matches the source code in a straightforward manner.

Variables kept in registers

Once you turn on the optimizations, the compiler applies many different techniques to make the code running faster while still doing the same. The most obvious difference between optimized and unoptimized builds in Visual C++ is the fact the variable values are kept in registers as long as possible in optimized builds, while without optimizations they are always stored into the memory. This affects not only the code speed, but it also affects debugging. As a result of this optimization the debugger cannot reliably obtain a variable value as you are stepping through the code.

Here is the my source - 
[What does "Optimize Code" option really do in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113866/what-does-optimize-code-option-really-do-in-visual-studio)