# PDBNavigator fails although there are pdb files

Tags: c#, visual-studio, frameworks, pdb-files

We are developing a small framework within the company and there is a small weird issue with pdb files.
While developing framework, we also commit pdb&dll outputs and related projects are referenced directly to these dlls.

But when i build and commit these dlls, my companions cannot navigate to sources of framework. When someone else builds, i cannot navigate to source.

Only thing i can do is to use resharper's navigation via "navigate to -> decompiled sources".

There is something wrong i think. They are the same files so that i should be able to navigate to their files directly.

Btw, we do not version framework. All dlls use same 1.0 version.

Anyone having an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Using [DUMPBIN](https://www.wintellect.com/pdb-files-what-every-developer-must-know/) I examined all pdb files and there were full paths of last build, which is different in my computer.

For ex: my collegue build framework project in `d:\projects` path however, working directory in my computer was `c:\projects` so that pdb files somehow not found (which is veird. The paths should be relative imo)

When one of us changed framework project path and if we both use the same path; no matter who built that project last, it just worked. I can navigate source codes directly in Visual Studio.

Answer (score -1):

It can be that you need to disable [Optimize Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113866/what-does-optimize-code-option-really-do-in-visual-studio?answertab=active#tab-top) on release build to make it work. Try that..

Comment: I'm going to try it. Have you faced the same problem before?

Comment: btw, we are building debug mode while committing, with pdb's

Comment: no, wot working, because we are building both framework and related projects in debug mode.

Comment: Are the projects inside the solution?

Comment: no, they are in another SVN repo, which are checked out to each developer machines, using same folder hierarchy. Related projects are connected via relative paths. And in developer machine, this problem happens if he didnt compiled the framework last.

Comment: Are the PDB's checked in to the repo? It sounds like they are not. Because if you compile the framework on the developers PC it will work?

Comment: You can also try to add the location of your framework and it's PDB's to th symbols in visual studio by going to Tools --> options --> debugging --> symbols

Comment: yes pdbs are included in the SVN repository, and they exist in developer machines too. and i tried debugging symbol file location, it didnt work :(

Comment: I think, the solution will be related with source symbol servers, but its just a headache...