# Why should someone disable the compiler-optimization

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, visual-studio-2017, settings

a coworker, who doesnt work here anymore, disabled the code-optimization of one of our projects some time ago. There is no way I can contact him anymore and looking at the changes he made with his commit I cannot see any reason as to why he did that.

Our program has some great bottlenecks and even though I am not sure if enabling this option again would bring any boost in performance, I would say its the better way to go..

The main problem here is that we would have to check every bit of this badly-written software for any side-effects which could take literal months to do..

My question here is if there are any reasons known as to why someone should deactivate this option and for what reason?

[image: The Setting I mean]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "Optimize Code" option really do in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113866/what-does-optimize-code-option-really-do-in-visual-studio)

Comment: [side note] you need to start using `code reviews` to avoid this scenario

Comment: I dont think it is the same.. In my opinion it doesnt show which side-effects there could be in activating the option..

Comment: maybe not explicitly although after reading thru the answers there - one would gain a fairly good insight into potential risk/benefits

Comment: @BotMaster3000 would you care accepting my answer ?

Answer (score 2):

When debugging with that option turned on, some variables can't be inspected as their lifetime has been minimized. It is very likely he deactivated it to be able to debug more comfortably. There should be *no effect* on runtime apart from a slight slow down.

You can always try to check on a non-production environment if reactivating it helps with the bottlenecks you mention. That being said, do not expect any major speed-up.